# Browsers bug on Single quote in URL

Tags: javascript, browser

When I am passing a **'USD'** `currency(Javascript)` in URL all the browser are not supported the single quote in URL.i use the `encodeURIComponent` but its not work,is there any solution to pass the single quote in URL?

Comment: I think you've misidentified the cause of your problem. Try providing a real [mcve]

Comment: no,when i use single quote it gives error "out of ascii range" if its remove its work

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

From [URL string encode table](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), single quote is equal to %27

It should be fine to use %27 as a replacement of single quote.

Comment: %27 also not supported